# How to add specific key values from one object to another array of objects, for each object

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, key, javascript-objects

What I want to achieve is to add each key value of array b to each object in array a, but not to merge them as I've tried that already and it's no something that it helps, I basically want to add the key and value that I don't have in array a from array b.

```
 array a = [
{
name: "Alex"
}, 

{
name: "Helen"
}, 

{
name: "Anna"
}]
```

---

```
array b = [
{
age: "23"
}, 

{
age: "24"
}, 

{
age: "25"
}]
```

---

What I want to achieve is:

```
array a = [
{
name: "Alex",
age: "23"
}, 

{
name: "Helen",
age: "24"
}, 

{
name: "Anna",
age: "25"
}]
```

I've tried the options available in here but nothing seems to work. If you guys have any idea, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Array.prototype.map()`:

```js
const a = [{name:"Alex"},{name:"Helen"},{name:"Anna"}],
      b = [{age:"23"},{age:"24"},{age:"25"}],

    result = a.map(({name},i) => ({name, ...b[i]}))
    
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```